# Mobile Marketing Cloud SDK has dependency on outdated Firebase SDKs

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

on May 11th, Google has released a new version of Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK:

- 22.0.0 for Android -> https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v22-0-0
- 8.0.0 for iOS -> https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_800_-_may_11_2021

and this new SDK includes a breaking change because it removes a dependency on Firebase InstanceID. Unfortunately, Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK is still not migrated and it's using Firebase InstanceID somewhere in the code.

Due to that, we are not able to upgrade our Firebase SDK version (because we are receiving multiple errors from the Salesforce SDK), which is also blocking us from a bigger upgrade in our dev environment - we are using Flutter cross-platform framework to build mobile apps, and we would like to update it's newest version 2.+ but we can't do that because of this issue in SFMC SDK. It's important for us to upgrade our development environment because the latest Flutter version has multiple bug fixes, improvements and also give us better compatibility with 3rd party packages.

Here You have a guide created by Google on how to migrate from using Firebase InstanceID to Firebase Installations -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations?hl=en#fid-iid

Answer (score 2):

Please open a Voice-of-Customer request through your support representative for this.